# Difference between Matrix and Diagram

Tags: uml

Can someone please explain, the difference between:

"**actors vs use case Matrix**" and "**use case Diagram**"?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's rather simple. A matrix has columns for the actors and rows for the use cases. And you mark an X in cells where actors are used in use cases. (Or you mark them with P for Primary and S for Secondary.) This is useful for systems with many actors/use cases to identify the most important actors.

A use case diagram links actors and use case bubbles via associations.